# Disable multiple submission of submit button

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

```
<button onclick="task_reject('<?php echo $task['task_id'];?>');" type="submit" class="buttonClass blueBtn pull-right">
```

I need to disable the submit button on first click but there is an onclick function which is not functioning.

I tried with the following but still its not working

```
onclick="this.disabled=true;task_reject('<?php echo $task['task_id'];?>');"
```

Thanks in advance  for help!!!!!!!

Comment: <button onclick="this.disabled=true;task_reject('<?php echo $task['task_id'];?>');" type="submit" class="buttonClass blueBtn pull-right"> i tried this. but it disabled but task_reject function wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code and will only execute once.

```
        $("form[name=xxxx]").submit(function() {
            $(this).submit(function() {
                return false;
            });
            return true;
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add disabled attribute to the button using button id or class. Write this code in your task_reject function as first line.

```
$('button').attr('disabled', "disabled")
```

Comment: @RevathiKrishnaK whatever. This site goes both ways. If you expect FREE help, you should REWARD those who help you by accepting their answer. Start giving back to the community. I have obviously fallen onto deaf ears.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. Try it once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var count = 0;

   $("#submit").click(function(){
       if(count == 0){
           //do stuff here

           count++;
          $('button').attr('disabled', "disabled")
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use onclick :

```
this.disabled=true;
```

so

```
<button onclick="this.disabled=true;task_reject('<?php echo $task['task_id'];?>');" type="submit" class="buttonClass blueBtn pull-right">
```

Comment: here the button will be disabled on click but It won perform the functionality of task reject

Comment: hi can u explain why ? we can add multiple function in onCLick attributes . No?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery
use this command:

```js
$('button').click(function(e){
  
    e.preventDefault();
  
  });
```

```html
<form action="">
  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  
  
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```